# Do we need to use integration by part to integrate this function or not?

Tags: integration

How to integrate this $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{a t} u]=e^{a t} \cos m t$

Is it correct this step 
$[e^{a t} u]=\int e^{a t} \cos m t \, dt $.

then I integrate the R.H.S by parts.

OR do the exponential function cancel out for example we multiply both sides by $e^{-a t}$ then become 
$u=\int  \cos m t \, dt = \frac{1}{m} \sin m t+c$.
Which one is correct?

Comment: Your first method is correct. You can then use integration by parts, or some other technique, to evaluate the integral on the R.H.S. Your second method is not correct. The exponential term plays an important role on the L.H.S. You can not simply take out of the differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is fine.  Presumably you are considering $u$ to be a function of $t$.  If it is not (it is a constant) there is no solution.  If it is and you want, you can expand the LHS with the product rule:  $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{a t} u]=ae^{a t} u+e^{a t} u'$.  Now you can multiply through by $e^{-at}$, getting $au+u'=\cos mt$  Depending on the tools in your differential equation kit, this may or may not be simpler than what you started with.  What you cannot do is multiply both sides by $e^{-at}$ and then carry that inside the $\frac d{dt}$ to cancel the $e^{at}$ as you lose the first term in the product rule expansion.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. $u$ is a function of  $t$. I derive the above equation because it is easy to integrate this problem $\frac{du}{dt}=-au+\cos mt$.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the integral very quickly without integration by parts.

Consider $$I=\int e^{a t} \cos( m t) \, dt$$ $$J=\int e^{a t} \sin( m t) \, dt$$ $$K=I+iJ=\int e^{a t} e^{imt} \, dt=\int e^{(a +im)t} \, dt=\frac{e^{(a +im)t}}{(a +im)}$$ So, $I$ and $J$ are the real and imaginary parts of $K$ from which you quickly deduce $$I=\frac{a \cos (m t)+m \sin (m t)}{a^2+m^2}\,e^{a t} $$$$J=\frac{a \sin (m t)-m \cos (m t)}{a^2+m^2}\,e^{a t} $$